# Augmented Dickey-Fuller test and Differencing (R)

Tags: r, stationarity, unit-root

I'm using the ADF test to check for stationarity of two variables, using the `ndiffs` function in R.

```
> ndiffs(x[, "Apples"], alpha = 0.05, test = c("adf"))
[1] 2
> ndiffs(x[, "Romulans"], alpha = 0.05, test = c("adf"))
[1] 0
```

Next step is as far as I understand to difference the time series with the appropriate lag to achieve stationarity, but this is when I encounter difficulty.

Using:

```
d.x1 = diff(x[, "Apples"], lag = 2)
d.x2 = diff(x[, "Romulans"], lag = 0)
```

doesn't work as the lag and difference must be an integer >= 1.

and excluding the lag option for the `Romulans` variable gives a warning message as soon as I try `dx = cbind(d.x1, d.x2)` saying that the `number of rows result is not a mulitple of vector length (arg 1)`.

Should I use lag 2 for both variables? What is the best way to handle a situation like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Next step is as far as I understand to difference the time series with the appropriate lag

Actually, **not** with the appropriate *lag* but an appropriate *number of times*.
`ndiffs` indicates the argument variable's order of integration. Say, it is $n$. To make the variable stationary, you are supposed to difference $n$ times. This is not the same as to difference using $\text{lag}=n$. Here are some examples:

Difference **once** with $\text{lag}=1$: `diff(x,lag=1,differences=1)` yields $\Delta x_t:=x_t-x_{t-1}$.
Difference **twice** with $\text{lag}=1$: `diff(x,lag=1,differences=2)` yields $\Delta^2 x_t:=\Delta x_t-\Delta x_{t-1}=(x_t-x_{t-1})-(x_{t-1}-x_{t-2})=x_t-2x_{t-1}+x_{t-2}$.
Difference **once** with $\text{lag}=2$: `diff(x,lag=2,differences=1)` yields $\Delta x_t:=x_t-x_{t-1}$.

The last example is **not** what `ndiffs` is about, while the first and the middle one are fine.

Also, if $n=0$, you do not have to difference and you just leave the variable as is.

> excluding the lag option...

When you do not specify the `lag` argument explicitly, is assumes its default value which is 1; it does not just disappear.

> number of rows result is not a mulitple of vector length (arg 1)

Differencing a variable $n$ times results in it being shortened by $n$ observations. To match a differenced variable that was originally of length $n$ with a non-differenced variable that is of length $n$ you will have to cut the initial $n$ values of the non-differenced variable: `x[-c(1:n)]`. Then the two variables will match correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a clear and understandable answer!

Comment: However, it doesn't solve the `cbind(d.x1, d.x2)` problem I am experiencing as it says variable lengths differ (they do not before the diff).

Comment: @youjustreadthis, I added an additional paragraph to my answer that addresses the problem with `cbind`.